# Jupyter Notebook wont open - Common solutions not working

Tags: networking, mac, ip-address, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

when I try to open my Jupyter Notebook I keep getting the following error.

> Cannot bind to localhost, using 127.0.0.1 as default ip
>       [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address

After searching online, the most common solution/work-around is to start the notebook using some form of the following command,

> jupyter notebook --ip=127.0.0.1

However, when I try this I still get an error saying

> [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address

I think is some type of network configuration issue, but I'm not to sure where to start looking. Ive checked my *etc/host* file and it looks like its never been tampered with. Again, I'm not sure where else to look so any help is appreciated.

I have a 2011 macbook pro running 10.13.3.